# Android Wifi Direct inter-workability between ICS and JellyBean

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I was testing WiFi Direct on my Android Devices. I have a Galaxy Note running 4.0.4, and a Nexus 7 running 4.2.1. I followed exactly from [the official API on WiFiDirect](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html).
After the devices found each other, if I try to make them "connect", I'll be able to see an invitation of WifiDirect connection, but after I "accept" this invitation, the status of this device changed to "invited", while on the other device (which sent the invitation initially) got no response. Thus a wifi-direct connection can never be made among the two device.

I then tried the official Wifi-Direct Demo program... but it doesn't seems to work also.

After I rooted my Galaxy Note and upgraded it to 4.1.2, this problem disappeared.

But I wonder if anyone encounter same problem as I did? And if so how did you solved it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I face the same problem. Does the Android OS exist problems?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's the problem but I bought the Nexus4 replaced my galaxy note, problem disappeared also. So I think Android 4.0 have some problem with Wifi-Direct.. and more importantly, when the Wifi-Direct is on, user cannot use Wifi in 4.0 (interestingly..)

Comment: i upgrade my galaxy nexus to 4.1.2. Connect to the galaxy nexus with 4.1.1. The problem is still here. your problem [someone](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39110) mention before. There are so many bugs in Wifi direct. I want to ask whether the broadcast receiver sends a event when two devices connect sucessfully?

Comment: Yeah when it's connected succefully the "WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION" would got executed. The WifiDirectDemo in the example project is very helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

To find the exact reason you have to look at the log report of wpa_supplicant(this can be seen from the log report using android debug bridge(adb) available in adt bundle with eclipse @ http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ).

I have faced a similiar problem while trying to connect androd 4.0 tablet with ubuntu laptop.The problem was with the dhcp server which was supposed to assign an IP address after the Group negotiation is successful but it wasn't respondig may be due to difference in the versions or some other reason.This wasn't a bug with wifi direct.

I fixed it by assigning a static IP address to the p2p_wlan0 interface on both the devices.